# Use SpEL in JpaRepository Query Hint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring-data-jpa 2.7.8 and I want to use a parameter in application.yml of a spring boot application to set the HINT_FETCH_SIZE like the following example, Is it possible to use SpEL in the query hint to achieve this ? I know that it is supported for `@Query` but I could not yet find a way to achieve it for `@QueryHint`

```
  @QueryHints(value = {
      @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "#{environment.getProperty('myapp.custom-batch-size.student-query')"),
      @QueryHint(name = HINT_READONLY, value = "true"),
      @QueryHint(name = HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")
  })
  Stream<Student> findByName(String name);
```

Comment: Test it and you will know.

Comment: yes I had, I just put an example of I want to achieve as an illustration (from spring jpa data code it looks not possible AbstractJpaQuery.applyQueryHint), I tried also using JpaSpecificationExecutor, what I want to do is to find a way to use the parameter in application.yml in query hint while keep using the spring repository, I am still thinking I have missed something or spring data simply does not support it, but I think it might be a good idea if it does

Comment: So it doesn't work and there you have your answer. You can try `${myapp.custom-batch-size.student-query}` which is a value expression and not SpEL which might work. But I doubt it, if you want that to be supported, register a ticket with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: It does not work either, in the method AbstractJpaQuery.applyQueryHint there isn't any implementation to evaluate expression, it simply passes the value from the annotation, I will follow this spring data documentation to create a custom repository functionality https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior

Comment: Apart from that I would suggest to register a ticket with Spring Data JPA to include, at least, property substition.